# Whats the most semantic way to display a single portfolio item in HTML5?

Tags: html

There were of course several discussions and questions of the correct usage of the html5 <figure> Element but none of them had a specific answer to my question.

It's more a general question about displaying portfolio items. Sure, you could do something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <h1>Project Title</h1>
    <img src="#"/>
    <p>a short description</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<div class="portfolio-item">
  <h1>Project Title</h1>
  <img src="#"/>
  <p>a short description</p>
</div>
```

There are certainly a dozen other ways to describe a single item but I'd like to know if it would be **valid** and **semantic** HTML5, if you wrap the whole item into an <article> element and the picture into an <figure> element. Consider following example

```
<article class="portfolio-item">
  <h1>Project Title</h1>
  <figure>
    <img src="#">
    <figcaption>a short description</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <a href="#"> View details</a>
</article>
```

If not, what would be the most semantic way to display them?

Comment: In the same way that a sentence can be rephrased and have the same meaning, so to can HTML be restructured while preserving the semantics. That means that "most semantic" is a subjective decision.

Comment: It is indeed a subjective decision, but therefore it's important to me to hear other opinions on this topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *personally* don't think using a figure would be a good idea for the desciption/image. While I would say that you're using it in a valid manner, I wouldn't necessarily define it as a figure with a caption, and therefore I find the calling so isn't particularly semantic. I feel the figure/figcaption tag is best reserved for things like diagrams. In your case I think you're probably best off just putting the image on it's own, and the short description in a `<p>` tag (as you did in your second example).

I'd also put the header inside a `<header>` tag.

This is how I'd do it, as a list of articles:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <article class="portfolio-item">
      <header>
        <h1>Project Title</h1>
      </header>
      <img src="#">
      <p>a short description</p>
      <a href="#"> View details</a>
    </article>
  </li>
  <li>
    etc...
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I broadly agree, except I wouldn't put the `h1` into a `header` element. Semantically, you're just saying "this is a heading" twice. I think the list is unnecessary too. You wouldn't put a sequence of paragraphs into a list, would you?

Comment: @Alohci - I see your point about the `<header>` tag, although I tend to use it as I find it makes CSS easier (because you can style all headers with a single tag selector). I believe though that if the page is a list of articles, the articles should be in a list. Paragraphs are not in a list because they belong to a larger semantic (the "document"), however (again IMO) articles should be treated as their own individual elements and are therefore applicable to be placed in a list. In the end though, semantics are personal preference more than anything, so your argument is as valid as mine.

Comment: I thought about adding a &lt;header&gt; element too.
Even if it would be correct to use a figure element within this context, I'll probably roll with your version.

Comment: The '<header>' is absolutely valid and semantic. It's the '<header>' for that '<article>'. Whatever sectioning element the '<ul>' is in can also have it's own '<header>'. The '<header>' is more than just a masthead

Answer (score 0):

Your layout of the figure and figcaption elements arecorrect (http://html5doctor.com/the-figure-figcaption-elements/) and wrapping it in an article element would be correct. It is an independent segment that could be taken out of the page and still make sense (http://html5doctor.com/the-article-element/)

Comment: I've read the articles before, and I came ultimately to the same conclusion as you. However, since I wasn't 100% sure, I've posted this question to get additional opinions on this topic. :)